# Do .apdb or .db files have any use inside Google Drive or Google Photos?

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

I'm trying to free up space in Google Drive. I came across a bunch of files with .apdb and .db extensions that look like photo library files such as `Properties.apdb`, `Library.apdb`, `Photos.db`, and `Person.db` and so on.

I think these came from an import I did from iPhoto into Google Photos a long time ago. I don't need them for iPhoto / Mac Photos anymore since I rely entirely on Google Photos now, but are these files needed for Google Photos?

##### Things tried

I searched the web for `properties.apdb photos` (and other files in the list) and the only relevant results were references to iPhoto libraries ([1](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3124066?page=2), [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/927lh3/retrieving_photos_from_my_photo_library/), [3](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139537/what-do-each-of-the-files-do-inside-of-an-iphoto-library)).

I also searched the web for `properties.apdb Google Photos` and found only references to the Google Photos API([1](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/access-media-items), [2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/properties)) which I don't use.

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén I updated the original post with search attempts tried.